# Cannot read some property of undefined (React/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm retrieving data from an api and trying to render that data onto my components

I currently almost have a working solution...

```
let currentFoodItem = this.handleCurrentFoodItem()
      console.log(currentFoodItem)
```

this returns an object that looks like this:

```
{id: 1, foodItem: "Vegan Pho", ingredients: "Brocoli, Bok-Choy, Shitake Mushroom, Enoki Mushroo…prouts, Onions, Cabbage, Jalepenos, Tofu, Noodles", calories: "237", tags: "Vegan Vietnamese Korean ✭✭✭✭", …}
```

Now what I would like to do is access currentFoodItem.id, or currentFoodItem.foodItem, etc. but when I try to I keep getting back the error "Cannot read property 'id' (or 'foodItem') of undefined. 
Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: where is this currentFoodItem present ? Can you post the Component code also

Comment: Where are you trying to access it? Has `currentFootItem` gone out of scope?

Comment: i think if i included more it might just be more confusing
no it is still in scope. I'm just updating the same console.log that worked without the property

Comment: whereever you're using that value first check whether currentFoodItem exists, because at initial render it would be null.
For example { currentFoodItem && <p>{currentFoodItem.id}</p> }

Comment: awesome! thank you zunaib, that was the exact issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement. This should work

```
let {id,foodItem} = this.handleCurrentFoodItem()
console.log(id,foodItem)
```

Comment: okay.Can you post full component code or handleCurrentFoodItem function code for more clarity?